# How to set focus after execution QAction

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qaction

Main widget steals focus after execution QAction.
I need the focus to be set to popup widget.

```
QAction *action = new QAction(tr("show popup"), this);
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, this, &MyWidget::showPopup);
addAction(action);

void MyWidget::showPopup()
{
  QMessageBox* popup = new QMessageBox(this);
  popup->setModal(true);
  popup->show();
  popup->setFocus();
}
```

MyWidget inherits from QWidget.

Comment: move `popup->setFocus();` after `popup->show();`

Comment: I have it like that. It does not work. MyWidget steals the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you just created `popup`, it's not 'there' yet in the GUI. Even the `show()` doesn't instantly show it. After you leave the scope of `MyWidget::showPopup()`, the GUI event loop will continue looping and be able to process your new popup. Thus the `setFocus()` call comes too early.

But there is help underway:

`QWidget::setFocus()` is a slot, so you can invoke it.

If you use a timer (`QTimer::singleShot(0, popup, SLOT(setFocus()));`), it should work.
Maybe you'll need to use 10ms instead of 0ms.